# Issue when moving process from background to foreground in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, process, terminal, background, foreground

I started a couple of processes in the background from the terminal.

```
lars@UbuntuVM:~$ xeyes &
[1] 8553
lars@UbuntuVM:~$ xclock -update 1 &
[2] 8554
lars@UbuntuVM:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 xeyes &
[2]+  Running                 xclock -update 1 &
```

The task is to bring one of them to the foreground, suspend it, and then bring it back to the background. However, when I bring one of them to the foreground, I am unable to enter any new commands. If I enter ^C, it just terminates the process all together.

```
lars@UbuntuVM:~$ fg %1
xeyes
How
do
I
get 
back
from
here?
```

So How do I proceed to suspend the current process when moved to the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct key combination to be used for sending a foreground process to the background is `^Z`, not `^C`. For more details, see the Bash manual on [job control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control).